# TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect

Tags: oracle

Trying to install an Oracle DB.

When I run:

```
lsnrctl start ${ORACLE_SID}
```

I get the following error:

```
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=orcl)))
TNS-01150: The address of the specified listener name is incorrect
 TNS-01153: Failed to process string: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=)))

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

My listener.ora file is as follows:

```
#
#  orcl Listener
#
orcl =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC) (KEY = orcl))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = localhost.localdomain) (PORT = ))
      )
    )
  )

SID_LIST_orcl =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1)
    )
  )

LOG_DIRECTORY_orcl=/home/oracle/admin/orcl/log
LOG_FILE_orcl=orcl.log
LOGGING_orcl=ON
TRACE_DIRECTORY_orcl=/home/oracle/admin/orcl/log
TRACE_FILE_orcl=orcl.trc
TRACE_LEVEL_orcl=OFF
```

Does anyone know where I should be checking for possible causes to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it isn't a typo in your post, you have not assigned a port number for the listener:

```
(PORT = )
```

Try port 1521: it's traditional :)

```
(PORT = 1521)
```